# insert more than 1 value using knex with raw

Tags: sqlite, knex.js

I've went through knex docs, and have tried every possible combination I could find with no success. However, using SQLiteStudio I was able to be **successful** with **regular queries using more than one** `?`...

`select * from 'articles' where LOWER("cover_page") = ? AND "cover_page" != "" AND "user_id" = ?`

`select * from 'articles' where LOWER("title") = ? AND "title" != "" AND "user_id" = ?`

`select * from 'articles' where LOWER("link") = ? AND "link" != "" AND "user_id" = ?`

...In knex, I am able to get the following **successful if I only use 1** `?` at a time:

```
const doesExist = await db('articles')
    .where(db.raw('LOWER("cover_page") = ?', article.cover_page.toLowerCase()))
    .orWhere(db.raw('LOWER("title") = ?', article.title.toLowerCase()))
    .orWhere(db.raw('LOWER("link") = ?', article.link.toLowerCase()))
    .first();
```

Does anyone have any idea how to input the second value where `AND "user_id" = ?` ??

The goal is for the output to return nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. See also [documentation link](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw).

The key you are missing is passing the parameters properly. See the positional array for passing the variables: `.whereRaw('LOWER(cover_page) = ? AND LOWER(title) = ?', ['somepage', 'sometitle'])`

(I also suspect you should not quote your database fields in this context.)

I haven't executed it but this should be close:

```
const doesExist = await db('articles')
   .whereRaw('LOWER(cover_page) = ? OR LOWER(title) = ? OR LOWER(link) = ?',
       [article.cover_page.toLowerCase(), 
        article.title.toLowerCase(),
        article.link.toLowerCase()] ) 
   .first();
```

PS: You can also use the positional array for passing parameters to `raw()` the same as I used it for `whereRaw()`.

Comment: thx, I actually ended up with something different because I found out the info I was actually querying was incorrect lol. But I'll give you the credit. Well done.